# How to do cross validation for multiclass data?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation, multiclass-classification

I was able to use following method to do cross validation on binary data, but it seems not working for multiclass data:

```
> cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, X, y, cv=cv_folds, scoring='roc_auc')

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py in __call__(self, clf, X, y, sample_weight)
    169         y_type = type_of_target(y)
    170         if y_type not in ("binary", "multilabel-indicator"):
--> 171             raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    172 
    173         if is_regressor(clf):

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported

> y.head()

0    10
1     6
2    12
3     6
4    10
Name: rank, dtype: int64

> type(y)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

I also tried changing `roc_auc` to `f1` but still having error:

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, beta, labels, pos_label, average, warn_for, sample_weight)
   1016         else:
   1017             raise ValueError("Target is %s but average='binary'. Please "
-> 1018                              "choose another average setting." % y_type)
   1019     elif pos_label not in (None, 1):
   1020         warnings.warn("Note that pos_label (set to %r) is ignored when "

ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.
```

Is there any method I can use to do cross validation for such type of data?

Comment: ROC is only appropriate for binary classifiers. You should consider another scoring function or compute your ROC with a One vs Rest method.

Comment: Check the `average` parameter [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) and use the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comment by [Vivek Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3374996/vivek-kumar) sklearn metrics support multi-class averaging for both the [F1 score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score) and the [ROC computations](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score), albeit with some limitations when data is unbalanced. So you can manually construct the scorer with the corresponding `average` parameter or use one of the predefined ones (e.g.: 'f1_micro', 'f1_macro', 'f1_weighted').

If multiple scores are needed, then instead of `cross_val_score` use `cross_validate` (available since sklearn 0.19 in the module `sklearn.model_selection`).

Comment: What if I don't want to average the scoring result? I want the cross-validated scoring result for each class (f1score, precision, recall). This does not seem to be possible. With cross_validate in combination with the f1_score and average=None I get `ValueError: scoring must return a number`. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Hi @LNA, you should check the documentation for `cross_val_score` and `cross_validate`, they actually return each fold's score. Is that what you mean? If you actually want it by class you can check [imabalanced learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) should have what you need.

Comment: No, I don't think we are talking about the same thing. If I have 5 classes and 3 folds, cross_validate provides the f1_score for each fold, so I will get 3 numbers, but I don't really care about the results of the individual folds. I want to the results for the f1score for each of the classes, so 5 numbers for the averaged results (over the 3 folds) for each class OR 3x5 numbers for all folds and all classes and I will do the averaging on my own. So it seemed this should be possible by setting average=None, but cross_validate throws an error. Seems it can only handle numbers.